# Why is await forbidden in unsafe sections?

Tags: c#, unsafe, async-await

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx, the `await` keyword is forbidden inside an `unsafe` block, mentioning only 'difficulties inherent to preserving unmanaged pointers.' Is there a good explanation available on what those difficulties are?

Comment: What more detail do you want? You can't use it in unsafe blocks.

Comment: @MitchWheat I admit I'm grasping here, but maybe OP is looking for information on what that *means*.

Comment: It means you can't use it there! Even with a detailed explanation, you still won't be able to use it there. Perhaps OP should explain the problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: @MitchWheat: sometimes people just try to learn something

Comment: @MitchWheat The OP wants to know why it is forbidden, regarding possible consequences that could occur if async await was used in an unsafe block (hypothetically)

Comment: @IchirU: Yes, I know. I understood that.

Comment: @MitchWheat, StackOverflow is full of answers that elaborate on fine details like this. Indeed it may not change whether I can use await in an unsafe block, but the insight as to why I can't may help in choosing patterns for the times I wish I could.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two basic things you need to know.  An async method gets rewritten by the C# compiler into a little class with an unspeakable name that wraps a state machine.  The local variables of the async method become fields of that class.

Unsafe code quite often relies on being able to create pointers to local variables.  The *fixed* statement is like that, it creates a hidden local variable that the garbage collector can see and thus update when a garbage collection occurs that moves the array that is being fixed.  Creating pointers to local variables is fine, those variables are not subject to being ever moved by the garbage collector.  The stack of a thread is always in a fixed location in the virtual memory address space.

Connect the two and you see the problem, a local variable can turn into a field of a class, a field whose address *does* change when a garbage collection occurs.  Suddenly turning unsafe code into breaking code.

A code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```
class Example {
    int field;
    unsafe void Method() {
        int local = 42;
        int* p = &local;   // fine
        int* q = &field;   // CS0212
    }
}
```

The C# team *could* have made the effort to carefully analyze the cases where unsafe code is still okay after rewriting.  But some cases are just not fixable, like the *fixed* statement.  A bunch of work to only give disappointing news to the programmer, often for a bewildering reason.  The sane thing to do here was to simply declare unsafe code off limits.

Comment: That makes good sense. It's a shame the relevant state machine can't simply be declared `fixed` (optionally, I suppose) and be done with it. I guess the solution is to explicitly allocate the closure variables you'll need into a class, fix that class, and reference pieces of it appropriately. But that gives up half the benefit of the async rewriter wizardry. It's a shame!